# Pickle vs cPickle (?) in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, pickle

There used to be [`cPickle`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#module-cPickle) in python2.7. However, I don't see it anymore in [`python3 pickle`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/pickle.html). What ever happened to that module, did it get merged into the regular `pickle` module?

Comment: yes they are one and the same now

Comment: @AnthonySottile I see, thanks for the feedback. Is there any place in the docs or proposals where they mention that?

Comment: [PEP 3108](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3108/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python 2.7 there was a pure Python version and a performance optimized `cPickle` implemented in C. Now, only the latter implementation stayed but with the simpler name.

This name-unification approach started with Python 3. Please see an excerpt from ["What's new in Python 3"](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html) by Guido var Rossum:

> A common pattern in Python 2.x is to have one version of a module
> implemented in pure Python, with an optional accelerated version
> implemented as a C extension; for example, pickle and cPickle. This
> places the burden of importing the accelerated version and falling
> back on the pure Python version on each user of these modules. In
> Python 3.0, the accelerated versions are considered implementation
> details of the pure Python versions. Users should always import the
> standard version, which attempts to import the accelerated version and
> falls back to the pure Python version. The pickle / cPickle pair
> received this treatment.